# how to improve data insertion time of AWS elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I have approx 700 million records to insert into redis.
Elasticache is taking approx 7 min to insert 189164 records from 1 thread.

Even if i increase the no. of threads, which is inserting the records in redis.
It doesn't show any performance improvement.

Which means elasticache is not able to accept records so rapidly.

Can you please help me to identify the solution to increase the performance of inserting records.

Comment: Did you try [bulk loading](https://redis.io/docs/reference/patterns/bulk-loading/) using Redis protocol? This is the way to go for massive inserts

Comment: yes, i am  using pipe as follow : 
for e in records:
  pipe.set(key,value)
pipe.execute()

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like a python code that uses `redis-py` and pipelining in particular. The latter is not the same as bulk loading...

Comment: Please post more details - what client are you using, sample code, etc.. Different clients have different optimal behaviors.
Usually you'd like to maximize the number of concurrent asynchronous operations you perform, and if you only want to set values, check if you client allows you a fire-and-forget mode, so that you won't wait for the reply for one set before sending the next one.

Comment: Use redis-cli with pipelining (not via redis-py or other clients).
https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/bulk-loading/